# Caching array length before a loop in PL-SQL

Tags: arrays, oracle, caching, plsql

I was wondering if in PL-SQL caching the length of an array used in a `FOR LOOP` will have a significant impact for the procedures performance?
So will this example:

```
ln_count := lna_avcs.COUNT;
FOR i in 1..ln_count LOOP
--do something
END LOOP;
```

be more effective than this one:

```
FOR i in 1..lna_avcs.COUNT LOOP
--do something
END LOOP;
```

Let's say the dimension of the array is between 100 and 1000.

I know that in javascript the example with caching can have signifiant improvements.
Thanks

Comment: A quick experiment suggests that it makes no discernible difference - elapsed time is 0.06 seconds either way for about 7000 rows in collection.

Comment: Ok,so then is no reason for adding another varabile to hold the count, even if the collection is a collection of strings or objects.

Comment: Certainly I've never seen it done.

Comment: I'm almost certain that `.COUNT` does not actually perform any procedural looping to count the contents of the array; instead, it accesses an attribute of the array which is kept in sync automatically as the array evolves. In other words, there is no need to "cache" it.

Comment: Oh, good to know that, then is clear than ever, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made some checking for performance and there is no any significant difference between version 1 and 2. I repeated a test a couple of times and the results were almost identical. Sometimes version 1 was better and sometimes version 2 was better.

For test purposes, I created an array:

```
type array_t is varray(1000) of varchar2(80);
array array_t ;
```

Then I populated the array with dummy data:

```
  select dbms_random.string('X',25)
    bulk collect into array
    from dual connect by level < 1000;
```

**Test 1:**

```
for j in 1..10000 loop
   for i in 1..array.count loop
     temp := array(i);
   end loop;
end loop;
```

**Test 2:**

```
for j in 1..10000 loop
    vcount := array.COUNT;
    for i in 1..vcount loop
         temp := array(i);
    end loop;
end loop;
```

I measured time for execution of **Test1** and **Test2** using

```
timestart := systimestamp;
--Test1 or Test2 is here
timeend := systimestamp;
diff :=  extract(second from timeEnd - timeStart);
```

And I inserted the diff to loop_test table:

```
 insert into loop_test values
 (1, diff);
```

After that I repeated each test 200 times. The query form loop_test gives us:

```
select  id, 
        avg(exectime), 
        count(*), 
        max(exectime), 
        min(exectime) 
from loop_test
group by id

ID  AVG(EXECTIME)   COUNT(*)    MAX(EXECTIME)   MIN(EXECTIME)
1   0.797545        200         1.046           0.78
2   0.79841         200         1.045           0.78
```

**Result:**

There is no significant difference from perfomance point view between using array.Count or using of count assigned to variable first. Test was done on Oracle 11g.

The full test is here:

```
declare 
type array_t is varray(1000) of varchar2(80);
array array_t ;
temp varchar2(80);
timestart timestamp;
 timeend timestamp;
 diff number;
begin
    select dbms_random.string('X',25)
    bulk collect into array
    from dual connect by level < 1000;

for k in 1..200 loop
timestart := systimestamp;

for j in 1..10000 loop
for i in 1..array.count loop
     temp := array(i);
 end loop;
end loop;

timeend := systimestamp;

 diff :=  extract(second from timeEnd - timeStart);
dbms_output.put_line(diff || '  ' || timestart || ' ' || timeend);

 insert into loop_test values
 (1, diff);

commit;
end loop;

end;
```

Comment: Great, well then is clear, thanks for putting time to do this tests, I will do them on my machine too